# Usig a table as a header in rst2pdf

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I'm trying to use a table like this as a header for my document:

```
+----------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| .. image:: images/logo.png | .. class:: headtitle | |codigo|             |                            |                           |                      |                      |
|                            | **###Title###**      +----------------------+
|                            |                      | |version|            |
|                            |                      +----------------------+
|                            |                      | |vigencia|           |
+----------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

[I add a image of the code for the table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A59l6.png)

The problem is that when I convert a pdf the content of the last row of the right column is not displayed when I use it as a header for the domument, but when I use it as part of the body it works fine

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Just an idea: the table might be too broad for  the size of the page

Comment: Thanks, already checked that, in my stylesheet I have defined the percentages for the table. When I use the header directive in the cell where I use | vigencia | replacement does not show me the text, and if I use the same table as part of the body of the document shows it well.  Could it be that the header does not support complex tables?

Comment: Sorry, Juan, cannot help, don't know enough about rst2pfd. :-(

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway :-)

Comment: You can write code blicks in Markdown by indenting all lines by 4 spaces.